# Is there a way to download a firmware from an stm32f103c8t6?

Tags: stm32

We have a prototype that uses an STM32 chip, however our software guy went off the grid since COVID-19 and we have only 1 out 5 working prototypes with the software uploaded and working. Now we cant contact him to retrieve the code, he just sended the pcb files and schematics but forgot the firmware. So is there a way for us (we handled other parts of the proyect more hardware related) to "download" the main code of the only prototype and put it in the other 4?

Thanks

Comment: Unless the flash is locked, the SWD interface can be used to both read and write.  But as you've not mentioned which tool and PC software you use to operate the SWD, no one can help you further.

Comment: Sorry Im still green with this, I readed about the STM32 cubemx and the ST2 link tool but Im waiting for it to arrive in the mail to start playing around with it. So I thought to ask here first if it would be possible or not.

Comment: can read it using the onboard bootloader as well via uart or other

Comment: just read the documentation for the part

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the same tools can both program and read firmware. Did you even look at the tools you have?

It will work unless the chip readout protection is enabled to prevent casual cloning of firmware.

Comment: The image he can get will be a binary image. This can be used to program other chips, but not "human" readable.

Comment: No problem about debugging the code already works, we just need to be able to upload it to the other blank prototypes. We´ve been working on this project for 2 years and since our code guy went off the grid that means that I need to learn how to code in STM32 (I do mainly arduino) or, the shortcut would be to clone the existing code. I dont care if its binary as long as we can replicate it on the other prototypes. Is this doable wiht the ST2 link? Im just getting familiar with this arquitecture. Thanks

Comment: Justme, do we risk erasing the original flash if the readout protection is enabled? This is a long shot, but sure beats having to program 200 leds in an exact sequence by the milisecond. Thanks!

Comment: Not if you issue the right commands.  But why not practice on one of the other prototypes, first.  Eg find a "blink" project (maybe for the "bluepill" which uses this MCU), build and program it, then read it back out and put it in another.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the bluepill dummy is a good idea. Good thing I bought a couple of them along the ST2link to start getting familiar with it. Is there some sort of documentation that I can get somewhere that explains a little further how to use the ST2 link to download the binary? Or is it just something I will have to learn on the go? Thanks

Comment: If readout protection is enabled, you just can't read it. It won't erase the original, only that disabling the readout protection will erase flash. Use the program tools provided by ST, like CubeProg.

Comment: I do not think our team member had a reason to use code protection since this was a project between 5 of us that was still not ready to go mainstream, but since we keep trying to contact him with no reply we need to start moving forward in order to not lay waste to this last 2 years of prototyping. Let´s see If we can success once the ST2 link tool arrives. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately the source code is not uploaded but a compiled binary. You could try to decompile it, but it will be a significant undertaking to turn it back into servicable code.

You may be able to download the memory and upload that to a new microcontroller while you re-engineer it. You would use the same tool (usually) to download the memory space as a binary file and then write it back to another MCU.

Comment: No problem about debugging the code already works, we just need to be able to upload it to the other blank prototypes. We´ve been working on this project for 2 years and since our code guy went off the grid that means that I need to learn how to code in STM32 (I do mainly arduino) or, the shortcut would be to clone the existing code. I dont care if its binary as long as we can replicate it on the other prototypes. Is this doable wiht the ST2 link? Im just getting familiar with this arquitecture. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can read the memory with ST Link V2, however you need to be very careful with using the tool as it's pretty easy to erase the memory instead of reading it.